# Mapping the same Json key in different variables in the same object

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I'm doing some changes in a microservice which has an object like the following:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = UsageRate.UsageRateBuilder.class)
public class UsageRate implements Serializable {


private int rate;

@JsonProperty("rate")
private Float ratePPR;

@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
public static class UsageRateBuilder {
}
```

}

I'm getting the information that I'm going to use from a Json. That Json has a key called `rate` and I want to use that rate in two different variables, an int rate and a Float ratePPR. The problem here is that I know I can't have two variables from the same Json in the same object, but I'm obligated to do it because I can't touch the variable `rate`, so I have created the `ratePPR` variable to use when I need it.

When I'm testing I get the following error:

> Conflicting getter definitions for property "rate":
> UsageRate#getRate(0 params) vs UsageRate#getRatePPR(0 params)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:295)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1309)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider

What can I do to create the new variable `ratePPR` with the value from rate JSon value.
Another thing important to say is the attribute in the DB can be a fractional, so, I need to save in the first place the value in `ratePPR` and after of that I need to save the integer value in `rate` variable.

Comment: what about using a custom `@JsonCreator`? That way you can correctly map the `rate` field to `ratePPR` in the constructor

Comment: Hello @Lino I'm trying to use `@JsonCreator` the problem is that I'm using `@Builder`  and `@JsonPOJOBuilder` to deserialize the Json and now I have an error when I get the information from the Json.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the fact that your class `rate` and `ratePPR` fields match the same json *rate* property either in the deserialization process or serialization process, so as precondition you have to change the name of one of them. One way to solve the problem as from the user Lino's comment below your question is define a [`JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotated constructor with a float parameter annotated with the `@JsonProperty("rate")` and inside define the two fields:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UsageRate implements Serializable {

    @JsonCreator
    public UsageRate(@JsonProperty("rate") float rate) {
        this.rateIntegerPart = (int) rate;
        this.ratePPR = rate;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    private int rateIntegerPart;

    @JsonProperty("rate")
    private Float ratePPR;
}
```

The [`JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation excludes the `rateIntegerPart` from the serialization :

```
//json = {"rate":10.0}
UsageRate rate = mapper.readValue(json, UsageRate.class);
System.out.println(rate); //it prints UsageRate(rateIntegerPart=10, ratePPR=10.0)
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(rate)); // it prints {"rate":10.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there because I noticed that you have added `@JsonDeserialize` to your `UsageRate` class. So the key is how to implement your custom deserializer. Here comes an example:

**Step 1: Create your custom deserializer and map the field *rate* to both variables(`rate` and `ratePPR`).**

```java
class UsageRateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<UsageRate> {
    public UsageRateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected UsageRateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public UsageRate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        int rate = jsonNode.get("rate").asInt();
        Float ratePPR = jsonNode.get("rate").floatValue();

        return new UsageRate(rate, ratePPR);
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Annotate `UsageRate` with `@JsonDeserialize(using = UsageRateDeserializer.class)`**

```java
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = UsageRateDeserializer.class)
class UsageRate implements Serializable {
    private int rate;
    private Float ratePPR;
}
```

**Step 3: Let `Jackson` do the rest for you**

```java
String jsonStr = "{\"rate\": 50}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
UsageRate usageRate = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, UsageRate.class);
System.out.println(usageRate.toString());
```

Console output:

> UsageRate{rate=50, ratePPR=50.0}